# WPF TextBox change background color of text and not whole TextBox

Tags: wpf, text, colors, textbox, background-color

I would like to know if there is a way to change the color of the background of the text inside a `TextBox` and not for the whole `TextBox`.
Like when you highlight/select the text.

Comment: you can set add a Textblock inside of the textbox and change the backgroundcolor property of that Textblock

Comment: @demoncrate You can't inline UIElements to a TextBox. TextBox is pure text control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` doesn't support coloured text or rich text formatting in general. Depending on your scenario, you would have to go with a `TextBlock` or `RichtextBox`.

### TextBlock

You can either handle the text elements directly:

```xml
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="This is some" />
  <Run Text="red"
       Background="Red" />
  <Run Text="text." />
</TextBlock>
```

---

Or in case you need to find a particular text, handle the text pointers:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="ColouredTextBlock" />
```

```cs
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var text = "This is some red text.";
  var highlightText = "red";

  this.ColouredTextBlock.Text = text;

  int highlightTextIndex = this.ColouredTextbox.Text.IndexOf(highlightText);
  TextPointer textStartPointer = this.ColouredTextbox.ContentStart.DocumentStart.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
  var highlightTextRange = new TextRange(textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex), textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex + highlightText.Length));
  highlightTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
}
```

---

To make highlighting dynamic you can use a `MultiBinding` to create the inline elements using a text-to-Inline converter. Since we can't bind directly to the `TextBlock.Inlines` property, we use the `TextBlock.Text` property as a dummy binding target:

**HighlightInfo.cs**

```cs
public struct HighlightInfo
{
  /// <summary>
  ///  Set Range parameter: inclusive start index and exclusive end index
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="highlightRange">inclusive start index and exclusive end index</param>
  public HighlightInfo(Range highlightRange, Color foreground, Color background)
  {
    HighlightRange = highlightRange;
    Foreground = foreground;
    Background = background;
  }

  public System.Range HighlightRange { get; }
  public int HighlightRangeLength => this.HighlightRange.End.Value - this.HighlightRange.Start.Value;
  public Color Foreground { get; }
  public Color Background { get; }
}
```

**TextToInlineConverter.cs**

```cs
public class TextToInlineConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string sourceText = values.OfType<string>().First();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceText))
    {
      return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    TextBlock textBlock = values.OfType<TextBlock>().First();

    IEnumerable<HighlightInfo> highlightInfos = values.OfType<IEnumerable<HighlightInfo>>().First();
    List<HighlightInfo> sortedHighlightInfos = highlightInfos
      .OrderBy(highlightInfo => highlightInfo.HighlightRange.Start.Value)
      .ToList();

    int highlightStartIndex = sortedHighlightInfos.FirstOrDefault().HighlightRange.Start.Value;
    bool hasPreccedingNonHighlightText = highlightStartIndex > 0;
    if (hasPreccedingNonHighlightText)
    {
      string preceedingText = sourceText.Substring(0, highlightStartIndex);
      textBlock.Inlines.Add(preceedingText);
    }

    CreateHighlightTextElements(sourceText, textBlock, sortedHighlightInfos);

    int highlightEndIndex = sortedHighlightInfos.LastOrDefault().HighlightRange.End.Value;
    bool hasTrailingNonHighlightText = highlightEndIndex < sourceText.Length;
    if (hasTrailingNonHighlightText)
    {
      string trailingText = sourceText.Substring(highlightEndIndex);
      textBlock.Inlines.Add(trailingText);
    }

    // We are binding to the 'TextBlock.Text' property as a dummy target, so we don't want to set it.
    // We have already modified the 'TextBlcok.Inlines' collection.
    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  private void CreateHighlightTextElements(string sourceText, TextBlock textBlock, List<HighlightInfo> sortedHighlightInfos)
  {
    for (int index = 0; index < sortedHighlightInfos.Count; index++)
    {
      HighlightInfo highlightInfo = sortedHighlightInfos[index];
      var highlightText = new Run(sourceText.Substring(highlightInfo.HighlightRange.Start.Value, highlightInfo.HighlightRangeLength))
      {
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(highlightInfo.Foreground),
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(highlightInfo.Background),
      };
      textBlock.Inlines.Add(highlightText);
      if (index + 1 < sortedHighlightInfos.Count)
      {
        HighlightInfo nextHighlightInfo = sortedHighlightInfos[index + 1];
        var nonHighlightTextRangeLength = nextHighlightInfo.HighlightRange.Start.Value - highlightInfo.HighlightRange.End.Value;
        bool hasEnclosedNonHighlightText = nonHighlightTextRangeLength > 0;
        if (hasEnclosedNonHighlightText)
        {
          highlightText = new Run(sourceText.Substring(highlightInfo.HighlightRange.End.Value, nonHighlightTextRangeLength));
          textBlock.Inlines.Add(highlightText);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWIndow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<HighlightInfo> HighlightInfos { get; }
  public string TextValue { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.TextValue = "This is some red and orange and bluegreen text.";

    this.HighlightInfos = new ObservableCollection<HighlightInfo>()
    {
      new HighlightInfo(new Range(
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("red"), 
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("red") + "red".Length), 
        Colors.Black, 
        Colors.Red),
      new HighlightInfo(new Range(
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("orange"), 
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("orange") + "orange".Length), 
        Colors.Black, 
        Colors.Orange),
      new HighlightInfo(new Range(
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("blue"), 
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("blue") + "blue".Length), 
        Colors.Black, 
        Colors.Blue),
      new HighlightInfo(new Range(
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("green"), 
        this.TextValue.IndexOf("green") + "green".Length),
        Colors.Black, 
        Colors.Green),
    };
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:TextToInlineConverter x:Key="TextToInlineConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource TextToInlineConverter}">
        <Binding Path="TextValue" />
        <Binding Path="HighlightInfos" />
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

---

### RichtextBox

In case you need to allow user input, you would have to use a `RichTextBox`:

```xml
<RichTextBlock x:Name="ColouredRichTextBox" />
```

```cs
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var text = "This is some red text.";
  var highlightText = "red";

  this.ColouredRichTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run(text)));

  TextPointer textStartPointer = this.ColouredRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart.DocumentStart.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
  var highlightTextRange = new TextRange(textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex), textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex + highlightText.Length));
  highlightTextRange .ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with the `TextPointer` in your second solution.
My `TextBlock` is bound to a string. As long as something is highlighted in the `TextBlock`, the control does not update when I change the text.

Comment: I have updated the answer to add a third solution for the TextBlock..

Comment: Ah really appreciate it! Thank!
is there a way to update the HighlightInfos midways? It should be possible because theses are observablecollections but when I do this, it doesnt update the text inside the textbox, it adds the same text with the highlighted parts behind it.

Comment: HighlightInfo is a read-only struct. Since it is a struct (value type) you will always edit a copy. You would have to change the HighlighInfo from struct to class. Then let it implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!
Unfortunately, the text is still copied behind it, although HighlightInfo has been defined as a class and INotifyPropertyChanged has been implemented.



I try to change the Highlight like this:
item.HighlightInfos.Clear();
item.HighlightInfos = new ObservableCollection<HighlightInfo>()
{
     new HighlightInfo(new Range(
     item.ItemName.IndexOf(search),
     item.ItemName.IndexOf(search) + search.Length),
     Colors.Black,
     Colors.Red),
};

Comment: Sorry, I misread your problem. You can revert the changes made to HighlightInfo: make it a read-only struct (except you plan to change its value dynamically). I thought we were talking about the type HighlightInfo. But we are talking about the collection HighlightInfos... The reason why the binding does not update, is because the property HighlightInfos is defined as List<>. Simply change the property your to ObservableCollection. I have fixed it in the example.

Comment: Sorry for making you wasting your time.

Comment: No, you really didn't. Thank you for your detailed answers! You have helped me immensely nevertheless!