# WPF How to find a specific control in an ItemsControl with data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controls, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` which is bound to a list:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=files}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="ThisTextBlock" Text="{Binding FileName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
private readonly List<FileModel> files = new();

icFiles.ItemsSource = files;
```

I want to highlight certain text in the `TextBlock` in the `ItemsControl`. For this, I thought about using a `TextPointer`:

```
string? highlightText = "blue";

int highlightTextIndex = ThisTextBlock.Text.IndexOf(highlightText);
if(highlightTextIndex >= 0)
{
    TextPointer textStartPointer = ThisTextBlock.ContentStart.DocumentStart.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    TextRange? highlightTextRange = new TextRange(textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex), textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex + highlightText.Length));
                highlightTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
    }
}
```

How do I find this *ThisTextBlock*?

Comment: As a note, when you assign `icFiles.ItemsSource = files;` that will replace the ItemsSource Binding declared in XAML and hence make that Binding redundant. You could simply remove it from XAML. Also note that `{Binding Path=files}` requires that `files` is a public property of the current DataContext object. Your `files` is not a public property, but a private field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the item container's content template (which is the item's `DataTemplate`).

In case of the `ItemsControl`, you can use the following example to obtain a named element from the `DataTemplate`:

```cs
for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < this.ItemsControl.Items.Count; itemIndex++)
{
  var itemContainer = this.ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(itemIndex) as ContentPresenter;
  var textBlock = itemContainer.ContentTemplate.FindName("ThisTextBlock", itemContainer) as TextBlock;

  HighlightText(textBlock);
}
```

A simple implementation that searches an element in the visual tree can be found at How to: [Microsoft Docs: *How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You can copy and use the example's helper method `FindVisualChild` to search for elements by type rather than by name. The method is part of an example that shows how to get the content of the `DataTemplate` in case you use a `ListBox` or `ListView`.

In case you didn't modified the `ListBoxItem` template or don't expect it to change, you can use this simplified and faster version (to find named elements):

```cs
for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < this.ListBox.Items.Count; itemIndex++)
{
  var listBoxItemContainer = this.ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(itemIndex) as ListBoxItem;
  var templateRootBorder = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBoxItemContainer, 0) as Border;
  var contentHost = templateRootBorder.Child as ContentPresenter;

  var textBlock = contentHost.ContentTemplate.FindName("TD", contentHost) as TextBlock;
}
```

Except for special use cases, it is highly recommended to use the `ListBox` instead of the `ItemsControl`. `ListBox` and `ListView` are both an extended `ItemsControl`. They both provide scrolling and a significantly improved performance.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! I use a `ItemsControl` because I don't want to be able to select single items. 
Can you tell me, how this would work, if the `Textblock` would be inside a `ContentControl` `ControlTemplate` under `Window.Resources`?

Comment: From a performance perspective it would be better to remove the highlight behavior from the ListBox by overriding the ListBoxItem template. The performance gain when using a ListBox is really huge, especially when you expect to display many items or changes of the source collection or the collection's items.

Comment: There is nothing to find inside a template that is defined inside the resources. You would have to wait until the template was applied e.g. by the ContentPresenter.

Comment: I have one small problem.  
Items which have highlighted text do not update when the bound content is changed.
Do you happen to know why that is? Do I have to remove the highlight first?

Comment: You are modifying the TextBlock directly. This will remove the data binding from the Text property. Instead you should bind the source text to the TextBlock.Inlines property. Then attach a converter to the  binding that creates the inline elements from the source text: create one or more `Run` elements for the non-highlight text and a `Run` for every highlight text span. You can set Background and Foreground on the `Run` to give it its highlight appearance.

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262122/3141792) to find an example that binds TextBlock.Text to a string to highlight its text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to delete the **Binding** from **code behind**.

You can do this using **Loaded** event as follows:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="icFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=files}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <CheckBox Content="" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                 <TextBlock Loaded="ThisTextBlock_OnLoaded" x:Name="ThisTextBlock" Text="{Binding FileName}" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>    
  

 private void ThisTextBlock_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (sender is TextBlock tb)
    {
        string? highlightText = "blue";
        int highlightTextIndex = tb.Text.IndexOf(highlightText);
        if (highlightTextIndex >= 0)
        {
            TextPointer textStartPointer = tb.ContentStart.DocumentStart.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            TextRange? highlightTextRange = new TextRange(textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex), textStartPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightTextIndex + highlightText.Length));
            highlightTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the Answer!
How could I implement it that the text to be highlighted is variable. So when I change it, the highlight update themselves? Can I just refresh the `ItemsControl` or something?